# Is it possible to have multiple XMPP App Server connected to Google Cloud Messaging to handle Upstream messages?

Tags: android, server, google-cloud-messaging, xmpp

i just began Android development, and i am currently testing GCM.

I wrote a PHP server (with Jaxl) that handle upstream message, no problem.
Then i wrote a Java server (with Smack). No problem either.

**But when the both are connected to GCM, messages are sent to one or another, never both of them.**

Is it possible ? 
If no, have you got a hint to "share" those messages between servers (for security, to handle millions of messages...)

Thanx, and sorry if my question is very noob...

edit: i tried with one server API key, and also with 2 :)

Comment: anyone found solution for it?